# activate change event on page load

Tags: jquery, select, load

I have a select box with a few options,
I want to show and hide divs according the selected option value.
The divs are hidden and shown according the selecton and it works good.

My question is how do I invoke the function so that on page load so that the switch will change its state according the the `val` value if the `change` trriger is not activated.

I understand that the triger in the tas function is `change` but do I go around it?

```
document.onload = tas($('#taasukati_av_state').val());


function tas(val) {
    console.log(val);
    $('.taas').change(function () {
        //console.log();

        if ($(this).val()) {
            val = $(this).val();
            console.log(val);

        };

        switch (val) {
            case '0':
                $(this).closest('.taasuka').find('div.starthidden').addClass('hidden');
                break;

            case '1':
                $(this).closest('.taasuka').find('div.starthidden').addClass('hidden');
                $(this).closest('.taasuka').find('div.salary').removeClass('hidden');
                break;

            case '2':
                $(this).closest('.taasuka').find('div.starthidden').addClass('hidden');
                $(this).closest('.taasuka').find('div.employ').removeClass('hidden');
                break;

            case '3':
                $(this).closest('.taasuka').find('div.starthidden').addClass('hidden');
                $(this).closest('.taasuka').find('div.lo-oved').removeClass('hidden');
                break;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added `trigerr` event inorder to activate `change` event;

I added this line before the end of the function:
`$('.taas').trigger( "change" );`
this is the updated code:

```
    function tas(val) {
    console.log(val);
    $('.taas').change(function () {


        if ($(this).val()) {
            val = $(this).val();
            console.log(val);

        };

        switch (val) {
            case '0':
                $(this).closest('.taasuka').find('div.starthidden').addClass('hidden');
                break;

            case '1':
                $(this).closest('.taasuka').find('div.starthidden').addClass('hidden');
                $(this).closest('.taasuka').find('div.salary').removeClass('hidden');
                break;

            case '2':
                $(this).closest('.taasuka').find('div.starthidden').addClass('hidden');
                $(this).closest('.taasuka').find('div.employ').removeClass('hidden');
                break;

            case '3':
                $(this).closest('.taasuka').find('div.starthidden').addClass('hidden');
                $(this).closest('.taasuka').find('div.lo-oved').removeClass('hidden');
                break;
        }
    });

    $('.taas').trigger( "change" );
}
```